# JavaScript e Unity 5 : Qual o erro do código? (Animações de pulo e queda)

Tags: javascript, unity3d

Estou seguindo um tutorial para criar um game de corrida infinita (estilo Temple Run), o tutorial é antigo e as classes etc mudaram no Unity 5, logo, não consegui reproduzir o código, ele é feito para controlar e executar as animações do personagem.. Se a tecla de Start foi pressionada ele inicia a animação de andar, mas a de pular não dá pois eu teria de usar o WrapMode para dar prioridade a ela, porem isso não está funcionando.. Então pela lógica tentei assim (tentei de outros jeitos, mas o jogo trava, como nesse jeito).

```
           #pragma strict
        var anim : Animator; 
        function Start () {
            anim = GetComponent.<Animator>();

        }

        function Update () {
        /*  if(Controle.Start == false){
                anim.SetBool ("ande", false) ;
            }*/
            if(Controle.Start == true){
                anim.SetBool ("ande", true); // Verifica se deu start e inicia a anim de andar
            }
            /*if(Controle.cair == true){
                anim.SetBool ("morra", true); // essa era a de morrer mas está com o mesmo problema
            }*/
            Teste();
        }
        /* Tentei arrumar criando essa função que enquanto o espaço tiver pressionado ele desativa 
    o start e logo após ele executa a animação de pulo, mas não deu, tentei outros jeitos usando 
while mas sem sucesso */
        function Teste(){
            if(Input.GetKey("space")){
                while(Input.GetKey("space")){
                    Controle.Start = false;
                }
                anim.SetBool ("pule", true);
            }
        }
```

Como faço para arrumar isso? já tentei de tudo, o WrapMode seria com o GetComponent., porém as animações não deram certo com o Animation.

Comment: Geralmente se diz qual é o erro e a gente tenta te ajudar a resolver. rs*
Mas para que dar toda essa volta para fazer um runner?
Você só precisar capturar a tecla pressionada e disparar um gatilho no animator, ele cuida do resto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Update() {

// Verifica se deu start
if (Controle.Start == true) { 

   // Caso sejá apertado a tecla Space executa a ação "Pule"
   if (Input.GetKey("space")) { 
      anim.SetBool("pule", true);
      anim.SetBool("ande", false);
   } else { // Senão executa sempre a ação "Ande"
        anim.SetBool("ande", true);
        anim.SetBool("pule", false);
   }   
 }
```

}